# One validation error for CSS 139 Parse Error }

Tags: css

What does this mean?

> 139  Parse Error }

It's not even giving me a reason why. I even counted the lines and altered `img.logo` but still nothing.

#### CSS code

```
body  {
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #E2CACC;
}

ul   {
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#main    {
    background-color: #D4CAE2;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#header  {
    border-bottom:1px solid #999999;
}

#content {
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
}

#footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    clear: both;
}

h1  {
    font: bold 2em Tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

h2  {
    font-style: oblique;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

h3,h4   {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align:text-top;
}

#nav    {
    background-color:#E2CACC;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.home {
    color: #990000;
    background-color: #fff99d;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
}

#textblock  {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width: auto;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right:140px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

#leftnavblock  {
    float:left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:40px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    width: 150px;
    height:450px;
    display: block;
}


#leftnavcol  {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#leftnav    {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 45px;
    height: 460px;
}

}

#breadcrumb   {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#rest       {
    padding-right:20px;
}

#ul id      {
    list-style-type:none;
}

#jobvacancies  {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 0.8em;
    padding-right: 0.8em;
    padding-top:0.8em;

}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}

a:hover   {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000000;
}

#commonlinksbar {
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-left:500px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:10px;
}

#jobs       {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

a.linker:link {
    padding:0px;
}

a.linker:visited    {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;

}

a.linker:hover
{background-color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

img.logo
{
    margin-right: 1%;
}


.aura   {
    margin-left:150px;
}

.pic        {
    float:right;

    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-top-style: double;
    border-bottom-style: double;

}

.imgright {
    border-top-width: 4px;

    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-top-style: double;
    border-bottom-style: double;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

leftnav {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 45px;
    height: 460px;  }
**}**
breadcrumb {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

One bracket has no pair.